# Critcl : args in procedure

Tags: tcl

I would like to replace a Tcl procedure by C procedure with Critcl.
Tcl procedure :

```
proc myProc {args} {...}
```

Critcl procedure :

```
critcl::cproc myProc {Tcl_Interp* interp Tcl_Obj* data} ok {...}
```

And this is how I use it :

```
myProc $value_1 $value_2 $value_3 ...
```

My question : 
How to avoid this error `*wrong # args: should be "myProc data"*`, so that my values are grouped in a list and assigned to `data`

Comment: Use `myProc [list $value_1 $value_2 $value_3]` ?

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a `ccommand` instead of a `cproc`, as that let's you get the direct array of values (provided you skip the first word, which will be the command name). There is an example of this on the wiki at https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Critcl+Examples but you'll probably also need `Tcl_NewListObj` to actually make the list as an entity.